# JSF h:link becomes span

Tags: jsf

Why does this JSF Tag

```
<h:link outcome="hello/sayhi">Spring MVC</h:link>
<h:outputLink value="hello/sayhi" >Spring MVC</h:outputLink>
```

becomes

```
<span>Spring MVC</span>
<a href="hello/sayhi">Spring MVC</a>
```

in the browser so that the `<span>` is completely useless?

How can I get h:link working so it outputs the correct link including the context path?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The component `h:link` requires a valid (and existent) outcome target, if for any reason the server do not find the outcome target in your project, then a span will be rendered.

In this case, review your application files and check if the target "hello/sayhi" really exists and is declared correctly. Maybe you are just forgetting a bar ("/hello/sayhi") before the path (it's impossible for us to know).

According to it's documentation, an `h:link` should only render as a span if you set it as disabled=true. So I'm 100% sure that your problem really is a incorrect navigation path.

Comment: /hello/sayhi is managed by a controller and I can call /hello/sayhi in the browser to see the rendered XHTML from /pages/hello.xhtml and data provided by the controller

Comment: Are you saying that /hello/sayhi is a Servlet? If so, then `h:link` will not work. `h:link` must be targetted to a valid .xhtml file.

Comment: okay thank you for clarification, do you have a suggestion how I can get the link to /hello/sayhi which includes context! and path?

Comment: You can get context and path using some default JSF objects, like `#{request.contextPath}`. But there are also others ways to do this. If you want more info, please search on other similar questions or if you do not find anything useful, create another question for yourself. Good luck!

Comment: Or don't use an `h:link` but a plain `<a href...>` but part of the issue is identical then (resolving the context path e.g.)